UPI integration without Any payment provider | laravel
    public function processUpiPayment(Request $request)
    {
        $upiPaymentUrl = "upi://pay?pa=$request->upi_id&am=$request->amount&cu=INR";
        return redirect()->away($upiPaymentUrl);
    }

i want to get responce in this UPI payment
this UPI run succcessfully but not get responce directly
